# Spatial pattern classification

Tags: algorithm, classification, geospatial, spatial, cartesian-coordinates

I got list of categorized dots(left image) by color. I am looking to classify gray dots according to the already categorized dots(colored dots) to indentify patterns and create boundaries.

Are there any algorithms o tools to achieve that?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for a [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) machine learning algorithm would help you get the center of each cluster:

[image]

*[Here is a really good explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4b5d3muPQmA) of how the algorithm works.*

If you are using JS you can use the [ml-kmeans](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ml-kmeans) module. [Here is a quick example](https://repl.it/@adelriosantiago/k-means-ml#index.js) I made that will obtain an array of `centroid` clusters. All other gray points whose distance is less than `centroid + size` would be part of the color group.

Answer (score 0):

I found this technique: Random Initialization Trap using K-mean, it's used when the centroids were explicitly assigned, as my example does.

This link would be helpful.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-random-intialization-trap-in-k-means/